# CSS: Absolutely positioned element appears behind when changing parent overflow-x to AUTO

Tags: html, css

When I change my parent's div from `overflow-x:inherit` to `overflow-x: auto`; part of my table is appearing above my popup, regardless of the z-index.  When I put it back to `inherit`, the popup appears above the table properly.  I can't seem to tell why the overflow-x property would be effecting this.

```css
.table-parent {
   overflow-x: inherit;
}
.pop-up {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 55px;
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-parent">
  <table>
      <tbody>
        <td>
           <div class="pop-up">foo</div>
        </td>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: so the question is?

Comment: @Basil as to why the overflow-x property is effecting the absolutely position element

Comment: Can you create a codepen.io with the issue?

Comment: @ibex yes can create one shortly and will edit the question to include the link once I make one